# How can I find my issue with limiting my speed for my Java game?

Tags: java, animation

I am currently making a game where you drive a tank and am currently working on the player class. I want the tank to have inertia for a tiny bit of realistic movement. I have this issue where the speed of my tank isn't topping out at the limit I'm setting. What is strange is that the angle velocity part works great as far as I can tell. Both chunks use the same logic. Right now the tank velocity will max out starting at 1.6, then somewhere between 2 and 3, then 5 and 6, every time you click backwards/forwards.

Here is the code:

```
final class Player extends GameObject {


private static final double ANGLE_VELOCITY_MAX = Math.PI / 60, ANGLE_VELOCITY_STEP = Math.PI / 900,
        ACCELERATION_STEP = .1, ACCELERATION_MAX = 1;
private double angle = 0, angleVelocity = 0, speed = 0, acceleration = 0;

@Override
public final void tick() {
    if (gc.getKey(KeyEvent.VK_W) && speed < ACCELERATION_MAX)
        if (acceleration + ACCELERATION_STEP > ACCELERATION_MAX)
            acceleration = ACCELERATION_MAX;
        else
            acceleration += ACCELERATION_STEP;
    else if (gc.getKey(KeyEvent.VK_S) && speed > -ACCELERATION_MAX)
        if (acceleration - ACCELERATION_STEP < -ACCELERATION_MAX)
            acceleration = -ACCELERATION_MAX;
        else
            acceleration -= ACCELERATION_STEP;
    else if (Math.abs(acceleration) < ACCELERATION_STEP)
        acceleration = 0;
    else
        acceleration -= Math.signum(acceleration) * ACCELERATION_STEP;
    if (gc.getKey(KeyEvent.VK_D) && angleVelocity < ANGLE_VELOCITY_MAX)
        if (angleVelocity + ANGLE_VELOCITY_STEP > ANGLE_VELOCITY_MAX)
            angleVelocity = ANGLE_VELOCITY_MAX;
        else
            angleVelocity += ANGLE_VELOCITY_STEP;
    else if (gc.getKey(KeyEvent.VK_A) && angleVelocity > -ANGLE_VELOCITY_MAX)
        if (angleVelocity - ANGLE_VELOCITY_STEP < -ANGLE_VELOCITY_MAX)
            angleVelocity = -ANGLE_VELOCITY_MAX;
        else
            angleVelocity -= ANGLE_VELOCITY_STEP;
    else if (Math.abs(angleVelocity) < ANGLE_VELOCITY_STEP)
        angleVelocity = 0;
    else
        angleVelocity -= Math.signum(angleVelocity) * ANGLE_VELOCITY_STEP;
    if (--treadCooldown <= 0) {
        if (++treadIndex >= treads.length)
            treadIndex = 0;
        treadCooldown = TREAD_COOLDOWN;
    }
    angle += angleVelocity;
    speed += acceleration;
    location.translate(Math.cos(angle) * speed, Math.sin(angle) * speed);
}
```

Comment: Maybe it has to do with your lack of any curly braces for your if/else statements? I've never tried nesting an if/else inside an if statement with no braces, so maybe that works, but it seems suspect to me.

Comment: Please clean up your code, this is horribly hard to read and debug.

Comment: When is tick() called? Every frame? That might cause your problem, since you don't seem to be accounting for the amount of time that has passed since the last call to tick().

Comment: Looking at this more closely, you don't actually limit speed, just acceleration. You need a SPEED_MAX and limit speed. As it is, you are only limiting acceleration to ACCELERATION_MAX.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you ought introduce some limit for `speed` independent of `ACCELERATION_MAX`, edit the first `if`s to something like:

```
     if (gc.getKey(KeyEvent.VK_W) && acceleration < ACCELERATION_MAX)
    ...
else if (gc.getKey(KeyEvent.VK_S) && acceleration > -ACCELERATION_MAX)
    ...
```

and at the end ensure `speed` is within acceptable limits.

*BTW:*

I have to admit your code above is really hard to read (let alone reason about) for me - I suggest reorganising to something like:

```
@Override
public final void tick() {
       if (gc.getKey(KeyEvent.VK_W)) accelerate(ACCELERATION_STEP);
  else if (gc.getKey(KeyEvent.VK_S)) accelerate(-ACCELERATION_STEP);
  else                               accelerate(- Math.signum(acceleration) * ACCELERATION_STEP);
  // etc.. you get the idea
}

private void accelerate(double delta) {
  setAcceleration(acceleration +delta);
}

private void setAcceleration(double value) {
  acceleration = roundToZero(constrain(value, -ACCELERATION_MAX, ACCELERATION_MAX), ACCELERATION_STEP);
}

private static double constrain(double value, double min, double max) {
  return value > max ? max : (value < min ? min : value);
}

private static double roundToZero(double value, double radius) {
  return Math.abs(value) < radius ? 0 : value;
}
```

*Disclaimer:* did not test the above, nor tried to compile it.